# JavaScript DOM file input selector conflicts

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to write a code to upload images to my server. I have found one and it works.

This is the code

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="file" />
    <button onclick="uploadFile();">Upload</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile() {
  var input = document.getElementById("file");
  file = input.files[0];
  if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
      formData.append("image", file);
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('File Uploaded');
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  }else{
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
$dir = "upload/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $dir. $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
?>
```

---

Now I have to put multiple form file inputs, so I tried doing the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="one" />
    <button onclick="uploadFile1();">Upload</button>
    <input type="file" id="two" />
    <button onclick="uploadFile2();">Upload</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile1() {
  var input = document.getElementById("#one");
  file = input.files[0];
  if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
      formData.append("image", file);
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('File Uploaded');
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  }else{
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}

function uploadFile2() {
  var input = document.getElementById("#two");
  file = input.files[0];
  if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
      formData.append("image", file);
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('File Uploaded');
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  }else{
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work, I found that file type and id of the file form should be the same in order to make it work. What am I doing wrong here? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include the `#` when using `getElementById` (you're giving it an `id` value, not a CSS selector), so:

```
var input = document.getElementById("#one");
// Remove this ----------------------^
```

...and similarly for `#two`.

---

But you don't have to repeat the entire function just to use a different file input. Change your function to accept an `id` argument:

```
function uploadFile(id) {
  var input = document.getElementById(id);
  file = input.files[0];
  if(file != undefined){
    formData= new FormData();
    if(!!file.type.match(/image.*/)){
      formData.append("image", file);
      $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('File Uploaded');
        }
      });
    }else{
      alert('Not a valid image!');
    }
  }else{
    alert('Input something!');
  }
}
```

Then:

```
<button onclick="uploadFile('one');">Upload</button>
```

and

```
<button onclick="uploadFile('two');">Upload</button>
```